# When using SFTP with private/public keys on Mac, how do I change the FTP username being sent?

Tags: mac, sftp, macos-bigsur

I’m using Mac OS Big Sur with a bash shell. I want to use SFTP to connect to a remote server using public/private keys. However, I keep getting prompted for a password for the wrong username, I tried this

```
$ sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_my_priv_key sftphost.domain.com ftpusername
mymacusername@sftphost.domain.com's password:
```

I have verified the permissions on my private key are correct

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh/id_rsa_wells_fargo 
-rw-------  1 mymacusername  staff  1680 Oct 18 13:49 /Users/mymacusername/.ssh/id_rsa_my_priv_key
```

How do I force SFTP use the username “ftpusername” instead of the Mac username with which I’m logged in (mymacusername)?

Comment: `sftp [options like -i file] username@host` (like `scp` and `ssh`)

Comment: Have you tried the hint from the above comment? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Create an alternate config file for the connection and use -F for to have ssh use it.

~/.shh/config.sftp with guts having:
sftphost.domain.com
User ftpusername
IDFile /path/IDFile

then something like sftp -F ~/.ssh/config.sftp sftphost.domain.com

Also security tip: generalized your example, you just told the world you use wells fargo for financial stuff, most likely a VPN or code trying to connect from home or something..

References:

sftp https://man.openbsd.org/sftp.1

ssh https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config